# Disable maven plugins when using a specific profile

Tags: maven

I'm looking to find a way of disabling a plugin execution if running with a particular profile.

This is the opposite of [running a plugin if a profile is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684837/using-maven-profiles-to-control-build-execution).

My use case: My Maven build has a whole load of plugins, but when running on my dev machine, I want to skip some of them. Instead of commenting those plugins out locally, I want to be able just run the build with a "dev" profile. The plugins would continue to run on my continuous build.

Ideas?

Comment: There is feature request for a <skip> element in all plugins. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3102

Comment: That would involve all plugins having to support this features. I was thinking more in terms of `<plugingroup> <run-condition> <notprofile>dev<notprofile> </run-contidion> <plugin..> <plugin..> </plugingroup>`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more what exactly you would like to achieve? Some kind of packaging? Tests etc. ? or What? May be you can give excerpts of your pom file(s)?

Comment: in brutal detail: I want to set it up so that when my maven build runs with "risky" profile enabled, I want pmd, checkstyle, findbugs, surefire and failsafe plugins to not run.

Comment: @khmarbaise Same here. I have a demo profile and unit test don't run with the demo version of the application. There is rarely a reason to ask "why". If people start tying here on the site they have reason to do so.

Answer (score 123):

**There is a neat way to disable plugin execution when specific profile is active.**

Firstly you need to add an identifier to plugin execution like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- (...) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>nl.geodienstencentrum.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>styles-compilation</id> <!-- plugin execution identifier -->
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then you need to define a profile in which this plugin will NOT be executed:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>no-sass</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>nl.geodienstencentrum.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>styles-compilation</id> <!-- here there must be the same identifier as defined in <build><plugins> section -->
                            <phase>none</phase> <!-- this disables plugin -->
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now if you run standard maven build:

```
mvn clean package
```

the sass-maven-plugin **will be** executed, yet when running:

```
mvn clean package -P no-sass
```

the sass-maven-plugin **will not be** executed.

Comment: Very good answer. This even allows to remove the standard plugins from the life-cycle, such as the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: I would like to extend this answer. It is worth to mention that: 1) with <phase>none</phase> you can disable not the whole plugin, but a concrete <execution>, 2) It is possible to use a variable like <phase>${enablePhase}</phase> and set or not set this variable in different profiles. This way one can run a certain execution conditionally.

Answer (score 24):

- Define your pom so that is has only the plugins you need in dev mode
- Define a dev profile
- Define a production profile which contains all plugins you want/need
- Define the production profile as default

example pom:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>production</id>

    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <!-- 
        <plugin>
          ...
        </plugin>
        -->
      </plugins>
    </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <!-- Some other logic here, if necessary.
           Otherwise, there's no need for another profile. -->
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

To run in **Dev Mode** you can call the following:

```
mvn -Pdev compile
```

To run in **Production Mode** just use the normal steps:

```
mvn compile
```

In case you don't want/need to define anything special in your dev profile, you can omit its declaration and call your **Dev Mode** like this (`!` disables a profile):

```
mvn -P!production compile
```

Be aware: you may need to escape the exclamation mark since it is a special character in bash:

```
mvn -P\!production compile
```

Comment: Please, add these steps: 1) To run the project with the plugins, just build as usual; 2) To run the project without the plugins, execute `mvn clean package ... -P !production`. Note: The `dev` profile isn't necessary, if it won't contain anything in particular. The `-P !profileName` should be sufficient to exclude the profile.

Comment: @carlspring Could you please help me on why i get this error? `$ mvn -P !production clean
-bash: !production: event not found`

Comment: You are right, my bad! I could almost swear I'd done it like that before. :)

Comment: You can disable history substitution with: `set +H`

Comment: is it possible to create plugin definition and just "call" it from profile so that we can reuse some xml definitions?

Answer (score 11):

Building on Krzysiek's answer, you don't need to define explicit executions, just have a look at the output maven gives you and disable the default executions.

For instance, given the following output from maven:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (prepare-dockerfile) @ tilbud ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ tilbud ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
....
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ tilbud ---
...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ tilbud ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tilbud ---
....
```

The generated default execution names is listed in parenthesis after the plugin and goal. The following profile disables the plugins above:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>packageOnly</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-compile</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-test</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-resources</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-testResources</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-dockerfile</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that his works with the default plugins of a lifecycle only, since their bindings are declared in [default-bindings.xml](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml) and their `default-...` IDs are created by Maven on the fly. `<build>/<plugins>/<plugin>` declared in a POM cannot be overriden by `<profile>/<build>/<pluginManagement>/<plugins>/<plugin>`, since they work the other way round: (specialized) `<plugin>` overrides (general) `<pluginManagement>`.