# Maven. Skip plugin execution when running tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, frontend-maven-plugin

In my `pom.xml` I have `frontend-maven-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>

    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v6.11.0</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
        <execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It takes some time to run it and don't need this plugin when I run tests.

Is it possible to not execute the plugin when I run `mvn test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you heard about maven profile?
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

I understand that when you want to test a package, you don't want to build a bigger one.

You could define a profile that choose exactly what module you want to build and test.

You have a related question there:

[Disable maven plugins when using a specific profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476757/disable-maven-plugins-when-using-a-specific-profile)

Let us know if it helped you!

Comment: yes, sure I've heard about maven profiles. Just wondering if there's an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 25):

The frontend-maven-plugin now [has specific keys](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#skipping-execution) to disable execution of particular goals. For example, adding system property `skip.npm` will skip npm execution. You can add it when running maven this way:

```
mvn test -Dskip.npm
```

Comment: This does not seem to work if the `<execution>` in the POM has defined `<skip>false</skip>` in its `<configuration>` :-(