# Run Jmeter tests with direct call only

Tags: java, maven, testing, jmeter

I added the Jmeter plugin to my project and now its load tests are running together with the maven build.

```
  <!-- Jmeter  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I wanted Jmeter tests to run just by running the command:

```
mvn jmeter:jmeter -Pjmeter
```

I didn't want it to run when performing any maven lifecycle like for example:

```
mvn install
```

As the tests are performed in a Restful API the load test will be performing POST and creating data in the database every time a maven lifecycle is run.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) declaration under the [`jmeter` profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jmeter</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>configuration</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>configure</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>results</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

this way JMeter maven plugin will be executed only if you explicitly specify the `jmeter` profile

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Using maven profiles to control build execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684837/using-maven-profiles-to-control-build-execution)
- [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/)

Comment: For me it worked by placing the tag ```<phase> jmeter </phase>```  inside the tag ```<execution>```  as in the example:                                                                                ```<execution>
           <id>jmeter-tests</id>
           <phase>jmeter</phase>
           <goals>
                 <goal>jmeter</goal>
           </goals>
</execution>```